# Как скрыть часть блока выходящего за края в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

использую слайдер react-slick и в процессе верстки макета столкнулся с проблемой.
позиционировал нумерацию слайдов через relative. Ноль выходит за границы видимового блока, но его часть видна со следующего слайда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;`?

Comment: Пробовал, видимо, делаю что-то не так. При использовании overflow и max-width он скрывает блок справа налево, то есть если взглянуть на скриншот, то выпирающая часть останется, а начиная с /03 overflow начинает скрывать.

Comment: значит где-то ошиблись с позиционированием/размерами слайдов/слайдера

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавьте весь код слайдера в вопрос

Comment: Вероятнее всего ширина блока с цифрой 100% или попробуйте ей (ширине)задать жёсткие границы в пикселях.

Comment: @Arcadiy, я б добавил...если бы это мой вопрос был)))

Comment: @МихаилРебров ,Спасибо! Забыл отписаться проблему решил, дочерним элементам блока счётчика присвоил position: absolute и overflow, после этого проблема решилась

Comment: Вы можете сами добавить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

проблему решил, дочерним элементам блока счётчика присвоил `position: absolute` и `overflow`, после этого проблема решилась